# execute commands as user after Vagrant provisioning

Tags: shell, vagrant

There are some commands that have to be run as a normal user after the initial provisioning.  I thought I could do this using a separate shell script and the command `su --login -c <command> vagrant`, but it's not getting the user's path or other environment settings from .bashrc.

e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
su --login -c "rbenv install 2.0.0-p353" vagrant
su --login -c "rbenv global 2.0.0-p353" vagrant
su --login -c "gem update --system" vagrant
su --login -c "yes | gem update" vagrant
su --login -c "gem install rdoc" vagrant
su --login -c "gem install rails pg" vagrant
```

Is there a way to do this?  Maybe it has to be done with another provisioning tool like Puppet or Chef?  I've thought of creating another shell script that sources the `.bashrc`, copying it to the box using a :file provisioner and executing the commands like that, but it seems sort of like a hack.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: `su -p` will preserve environment variables - does this help?

Comment: @Vince I think it will be prefect to your question to  mention about build `Vagrant` box with Ruby installation, add `Ruby` tag and append Ruby Installation on question's title Like this => execute Ruby installation commands as user during Vagrant provisioning

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the [Vagrant Shell provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html), e.g.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  $script = <<-SCRIPT
  rbenv install 2.0.0-p353
  rbenv global 2.0.0-p353
  gem update --system
  yes | gem update
  gem install rdoc
  gem install rails pg
  SCRIPT

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script, privileged: false
end
```

The key is to specify `privileged: false` so that it will use the default user and not `root`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this as the non-default user?

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to document a solution for situations where the shell provisioner must run commands as a non-root user *in a login shell*:

Put your provisioning commands into a shell script (e.g. 'bootstrap.sh'):

```
#! /bin/bash

rbenv install 2.0.0-p353
rbenv global 2.0.0-p353
gem update --system
yes | gem update
gem install rdoc
gem install rails pg
```

Then in your Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  $script = "/bin/bash --login /vagrant/bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, inline: $script

end
```

You should replace the `/vagrant/bootstrap.sh` path with the correct path for your provisioning script *inside the vagrant machine*.

I've used this solution specifically to get `rvm` commands to work while provisioning with Vagrant.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you want to mix privileged commands and non-privileged commands. If your situation calls for this use runuser.

`runuser -l vagrant -c 'command'`

Comment: I was trying to install `nvm` as part of the Vagrantfile.  the default script would install it for root but not the `vagrant` user.  This did the trick without having to write a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Both [@jabclab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22556979/1908296) and [@evanhsu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411790/1908296) answers not work with me

To install `rbenv` and use it within Vagrant Provisioning process.

Using Next Commands before using `rbenv` commands

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

**Bootstrap.sh File**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt-get update
echo "========================= install dependencies for install rbenv ==========================="
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm3 libgdbm-dev
echo "========================= install rbenv =========================================="
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >>  ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >>  ~/.bashrc
echo "========================= install ruby build plugin for rbenv ======================="
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git  ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo "========================= install ruby v2.5.0 =========================================="
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
rbenv install 2.5.0
rbenv global 2.5.0
ruby -v
gem -v
echo "========================= install bundler dependencies manager for ruby ====================="
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash
```

**Then `VagrantFile` file will include vagrant provisioning line**

```rb
deploy_config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, path: "bootstrap.sh"
```

Source for my Answer from [Gits by @creisor](https://gist.github.com/creisor/e20f254a89070f46b91cc3e0c5cd18db)

Another Way to using `rbenv` commands within vagrant provisioning process at [answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29132891/1908296)