# Why is `source /home/vagrant/.bashrc` not working in a Vagrant shell provisioning script?

Tags: shell, vagrant

I'm [having problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569573/updating-bashrc-and-environment-variables-during-vagrant-provisioning) with a shell provisioning script used by Vagrant, as it's not executing `source /home/vagrant/.bashrc`. I've reduced the problem down to this...

Within my VM I have a file at `/home/vagrant/testfile` that contains this:

```
echo "In testfile"
```

And at the end of `/home/vagrant/.bashrc` I have this:

```
echo "In .bashrc"
```

Both files are owned by the `vagrant` user.

In one of my Vagrant provisioning shell scripts I have this:

```
echo "Hello"
source /home/vagrant/testfile
source /home/vagrant/.bashrc
echo "Goodbye"
```

Running `vagrant provision` gives this:

```
Hello
In testfile
Goodbye
```

When I do `vagrant ssh` then `/home/vagrant/.bashrc` is run as usual, and I automatically see:

```
In .bashrc
```

So why does doing `source /home/vagrant/.bashrc` have no effect from within my provisioning script?

Comment: What does the *rest* of your `.bashrc` do? I'm betting there's a test for an interactive session near the top (a check on `PS1` or a check on the value of `$-` or similar).

Comment: Ugh, yes, you're right Etan, thanks. I didn't think of looking at the rest of the script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to remove the “exit if not running interactively” bit (e.g. `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`) from the top of your `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thank you! Actually looking at what else was in `.bashrc` was the one bit of narrowing down this problem I didn't think of doing. Yes, there was a bit that was at the top of the file, not put there by me, which prevented it doing anything when run like this.

Comment: Do *not* remove that. It is important for all sorts of things that normally go in that file. Anything that needs to run even when that isn't true likely shouldn't be in that file (or if they are should be above that bit).

Comment: Oh, I'm not going to remove it, but thanks for the warning. Now I know why this is happening I can find other ways around my original problem. It was really bugging me that something was quietly failing and I had no idea why! Now I know.